# Orientdb Transactions Best Practices

Tags: orientdb

I'm working on a REST API. I'm having all sorts of problems with transactions in Orientdb. In the current setup, we have a singleton that wraps around the ODatabaseDocumentPool. We retrieve all instances through this setup. Each api call starts by acquiring an instance from the pool and creating a new instance of OrientGraph using the ODatabaseDocumentTx instance. The code that follows uses methods from both ODatabaseDocumentTx and OrientGraph. At the end of the code, we call graph.commit() on write operations and graph.shutdown() on all operations.

I have a list of questions.

- To verify, I can still use the ODatabaseDocumentTx instanced I used to create OrientGraph? Or should I use OrientGraph.getRawGraph()?
- What is the best way to do read operations when using OrientGraph? Even during read operations, I get OConcurrentModificationExceptions, lock exceptions, or error on retrieving records. Is this because the OrientGraph is transactional and versions are modified even when retrieving records? I should mention, I also use the index manager and iterate through edges of a vertex in these read operations.
- When I get a record through the Index Manager, does this update the version on the database?
- Does graph.shutdown() release the ODatabaseDocumentTx instance back to the pool?
- Does v1.78 still required us to lock records in transactions?
- If set autoStartTx to false on OrientGraph, do I have to start transactions manually, or do they start automatically when accessing the database?

Sample Code:

```
ODatabaseDocumentTx db = pool.acquire();

//                READ

OrientGraph graph = new OrientGraph(db);

ODocument doc = (ODocument) oidentifialbe.getRecord() // I use Java API to a get record from index

if( ((String) doc.field("field")).equals('name') )
     //code

OrientVertex v = graph.getVertex(doc);

for(OrientVertex vv : v.getVertices()) {
      //code
}

//               OR WRITE

doc.field('d',val);
doc = doc.save();
OrientVertex v = v.getVertex(doc);
graph.addEdge(null, v, otherVertex);
graph.addEdge(null, v, anotherVertex) // do I have to reload the record in v?

//              End Transaction

// if write
graph.commit();

// then
graph.shutdown();
```

Comment: Don't use OrientDB 1.7, but rather 2.1

Answer (score 0):

I use ODatabaseSession, from that perspective, I am noting my observation with respect to some of your points:

> What is the best way to do read operations when using OrientGraph?
> Even during read operations, I get OConcurrentModificationExceptions,
> lock exceptions, or error on retrieving records. Is this because the
> OrientGraph is transactional and versions are modified even when
> retrieving records? I should mention, I also use the index manager and
> iterate through edges of a vertex in these read operations.

Refer [OrientDB Concurrency](http://orientdb.org/docs/3.2.x/general/Concurrency.html). You are getting the concurrency exception because, the time when you retrieved the information (e.g. a vertex) and the time when you are updating, some other part has updated the record. This can be avoided by reloading the record

> ```
> When I get a record through the Index Manager, does this update the version on the database?
> ```

Read operations do not update the record version only modification operations do.

Does v1.78 still required us to lock records in transactions?

> If set autoStartTx to false on OrientGraph, do I have to start
> transactions manually, or do they start automatically when accessing
> the database?

Refer [OrientDB Transaction](https://orientdb.com/docs/2.2.x/Transactions.html). Refer [Graph API](https://orientdb.com/docs/2.2.x/Graph-Database-Tinkerpop.html). If the autoStartTx is turned off, the transaction needs to be started explicitly.